# Why does ImageMagick always convert to 96 dpi?

Tags: imagemagick

I've installed ImageMagick on AWS. The OS version is Linux RHEL 6.5. 
The ImageMagick version is 6.9.1-Q8.

But whenever I execute this command then it always converts to 96 dpi:

```
./convert -units PixelsPerInch /DATA1/test.gif -density 72 /DATA1/test.72dpi.jpg
```

Original Image -

[image]

After I execute the command in Windows then it changes the DPI to 12 -

[image]

This command does not make any different with density. Please let me know what could be the issue.

Comment: Do you want to ***(1)*** Change the real pixel dimensions of the image or ***(2)*** Change the metadata *hint* that is embedded in the image? *(These metadata hints do not have an influence on the real image quality, and they are not understood by all viewers either. **IF** an image viewer understands it, it will render the image larger or smaller to meet that DPI request, but it will not change the image per se.)*

Comment: Kurt, I want to change DPI, I've added photo. Its working fine in Windows but not working in Linux

Comment: You say whenever you execute the command the image changes to 96dpi. Then you show how the image looks after the command and it shows 12dpi. Which is it? What is important is only the number of pixels, and afterwards you have fewer - 171x128 versus 1024x768 originally.

Comment: The image I put here, is from Windows command which is working fine but if I execute the same command on the same image then its not showing required DPI. And pixels size is also not changing on Unix

Comment: @beautifulday: Did you even *understand* what I tried to say in my comment?! Should I try again, but in different words? (Maybe I was talking too technical, and was not clear enough?)

Comment: @beautifulday: you should provide a link to two versions of an actual (small) image where you successfully changed the setting with Windows. *(Maybe you only changed some metadata 'hint' and maybe this hint is at a proprietary location, only known on Windows...)* -- What is the software you use on Windows to change the DPI setting? Also ImageMagick? Which version then?

Comment: @Kurt, sorry for my misunderstanding, I used Imagemagic only in Windows to change DPI setting, Windows ImageMagic version :ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q8 and Linux ImageMagic version : ImageMagick-6.9.1-2

Comment: @beautifulday: So where is a link to an image before/after changing the DPI setting?

Comment: @Kurt, now its resolved, I had to configure JPEG, IM was not able to recognize  JPEG.

Answer (score 3):

You don't say what you expect your command to do, but I assume you want to resmple to the new dpi setting, in which case you'd need:

```
convert -units PixelsPerInch -size 100x100 xc:black -resample 96 a.gif
```

which makes the 100x100pixel input image into a 133x133 pixel image - because 96/72 = 1.33

The GIF format actually totally ignores/discards the dpi anyway, as you can see `diff` finds no difference between these two images - one at 51 PixelsPerInch and one at 53 PixelsPerCentimeter:

```
diff <(convert -units PixelsPerInch -density 51 xc:black GIF:-) <(convert -units PixelsPerCentimeter -density 53 xc:black GIF:-)
```

The article [here](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/02/the-myth-of-dpi/) explains the DPI rather well.

Comment: Thanks Mark, sorry that I did not mention that, I want to just change the DPI of the image, the same command is working in Windows but its not working on Linux.

Comment: The above command which you mentioned(I changed to convert -units PixelsPerInch /DATA1/test.gif -resample 72 /DATA1/a2.jpg ), works fine is Windows but does not give required output in Linux. Still it shows 96 DPI (horizontal and vertical) instead of 72 when I open file details in Window explorer tab,

Comment: I had to configure JPEG, IM was not able to recognize JPEG, appreciate your help